# How to render transparent background for png image texture with eevee?

Tags: texturing, image, eevee-render-engine

I have placed an image texture (on a plane mesh) using a png image that has a transparent background. The transparent background appears as the default material on the plane instead of being transparent. How do I get the transparent areas of my image to display as such? I need to do this specifically in EEVEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proper setup for a texture with an alpha (transparent) channel in EEVEE. Take note of the blend modes I highlighted in red on the right - these are necessary (anything but opaque).

[image: AlphaChannelSetup]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.